# display specific line in text file into textboxes c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to display the partial contents of the `ProductData.txt` in specific textboxes. The user must first input the product key to check if the product exists and if it does, it would display partial information about the product such as its name, type, and brand. If the product key does not exist, it would display `messagebox: item key not found`. my problem is that the data being displayed is always the first line. how can i display the line where the product key has been found?

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
        string plist = @"ProductData.txt";
        string s_temp = @"stock_temp.txt";

        string[] dataline = File.ReadAllLines(plist);
        if (File.ReadAllText(plist).Contains(txt_pk.Text))
        {
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(s_temp))
            {
                foreach (var line in dataline)
                {
                    if (line.Contains(txt_pk.Text))
                    {
                        txt_pk.ReadOnly = true;

                        string fileData = File.ReadAllText(plist);
                        string[] parts = fileData.Split(',');

                        txt_pn.Text = parts[2];
                        cmb_brand.Text = parts[3];
                        cmb_type.Text = parts[4];
                    }
                }
                w.Close();
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Item Key not found!");
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

> ITEM KEY,DATE ADDED,PRODUCT NAME,BRAND,TYPE
>
> 0001,10/08/2017,5s,Apple,Phone
>
> 0002,10/08/2017,S5,Samsung,Phone

Comment: You may want to consider refactoring the first `if` statement... You already read all the lines of the file into the first array and then you read the entire file **again** to test `Contains`. You'd be better off searching your array instead, especially if the file could be large. Also you open the `StreamWriter` and don't do anything with it except to `Close` it (which the `using` will do for you anyways)

Comment: Re: refactoring - Something like `if(dataline.Any(l => l.Contains(txt_pk.Text))) {...} ` or if you know there would only be at most one match you could replace the majority of the function with `var line = File.ReadLines(plist).FirstOrDefault(l => l.Contains(txt_pk.Text)); if (line != null) { parts = line.Split(','); /* do the rest here */ } else { /* not found */ }` If there wasn't already an accepted answer and I wasn't on my phone I'd make this part of an answer... So leaving it as a followup  comment instead

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 thank you! this works for me too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] parts = line.Split(',');
```

You need to split the line, not read the text file again.

Pro Tip: give Debugging a go and step through your code (pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>)

Comment: Can you please mark this answer as correct, it'll let everyone know your problem is solved and gives you a few rep points as well.