# program displays text file data even when item does not exist c#

Tags: c#, winforms

In my [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46628255/display-specific-line-in-text-file-into-textboxes-c-sharp), I was trying to display specific lines from the text file to display into textboxes.

I tried the solution`Jeremy Thompson` suggested and even the refactoring solution suggested by `pinkfloydx33` (which is what I stuck to) and yes both solution worked for me but i found that the program displays data even if the string does not exist in the file.

For example. If I were to type any of the following: `1,01,001,2,02,002`, it would continue to execute the code and display data. Can anybody tell me how I can fix this? I tried to get around this by limiting their input (for example they have to input 4-digits, no more no less) but my problem is the original keys have different lengths so I cannot apply that approach.

**SAMPLE DATA**

> ITEM KEY,DATE ADDED,PRODUCT NAME,BRAND,TYPE
>
> 0001,10/08/2017,5s,Apple,Phone
>
> 0002,10/08/2017,S5,Samsung,Phone

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
string plist = @"sample_data.txt";

var line = File.ReadLines(plist).FirstOrDefault(l => l.Contains(txt_ik.Text));
if (line != null)
{
    string[] parts = line.Split(',');
    txt_data1.Text = parts[2];
    txt_data2.Text = parts[3];
    txt_data3.Text = parts[4];
    MessageBox.Show("It exists!");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Does not exist!");
}
```

**SAMPLE IMAGE**

[image]

**EDIT**

Sorry for the ambiguity! The user needs to enter the product key. When you hit submit and the item exists in the file, it's supposed to display the data in the textboxes. If not, a message would pop out to say that the item does not exist.

Comment: It's not clear what the intended behavior is

Comment: Does that mean that the `ITEM KEY` field can be more or less than 4-digits?  So you could have an ID of 12345789?

Comment: @DonBoitnott yes the item key can be 1234567890. there's no specific length for it

Comment: You are getting exactly what you ask for: the data on the first line that _contains_ whatever the user entered. If the would enter `p`, you would retrieve the first record. Using `string.Contains` in this way is, when you think of it, absurd. You want the _key_ of the record to match what the user entered, so you need something along the lines of @MatSnow's answer - or rethink the idea of storing database items in a tekst file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Contains` returns `true` if the search-text exists anywhere on the line.
If you change this line:

```
var line = File.ReadLines(plist).FirstOrDefault(l => l.Contains(txt_ik.Text));
```

to

```
var line = File.ReadLines(plist).FirstOrDefault(l => l.StartsWith(String.Format("{0},", txt_ik.Text)));
```

you ensure the item-key equals the search item.

With `String.Format("{0},", txt_ik.Text)` we're also adding a comma to the search-text.

Then you're sure the first item equals the search-text.

Comment: you're a life saver! it works fine now thank you for imparting this knowledge!

Comment: Doesn't seem very flexible.  If they enter "02" you're strictly matching "02,".  Wouldn't you want that to also match "00002" or "00000000002"?  You're just back to matching verbatim what is entered.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Are you asking me or OP?

Comment: Don't know, depends on what behaviour @nik expects? But as far as i understood the question, he only wants exact matches.

Comment: @DonBoitnott 02 could have had different data from 002. Looking for exact matches just as `MatSnow` have said :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a different Linq, then. Try this:

```
var item = sa.FirstOrDefault(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(',')[0]).Equals(Convert.ToInt32(txt_ik.Text)));
if (item != null)
{
}
```

Note that while this is much more reliable, it's also more dangerous, so you would be wise to at least wrap it in a `try-catch`, but proper checking would be best.